# How to export a data with 5 millions of raws?

Tags: mysql, csv, bigdata, data-science, data-analysis

so i'm used to work with medium size dataset , now I'm dealing with a million of raws data in php my admin , I'm wondering how to export it to csv in order to analyze it and clean it so I can make some buisness decisions . thank you.

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` with proper/needed options.

Comment: thank you for answering , would it take time to load ? I mean its almost 5 million of raws

Comment: Importing from CSV into MySQL table using LOAD DATA is the most fast way to import the data. If there is nothing which needs in additional time during this process (non-imported columns which are assigned to default value, indices, foreign keys, triggers and so on) then importing speed may me up to ~10 Mbytes per second.

Comment: actually I need to export from mysql to csv so I can analyze it in Jupiter notebook

Comment: Export to CSV is similarly fast. Even more fast then importing (depends of the query complexity and HDD speed). For example, one of my databases export to CSV (150kk rows, 4 Gb CSV file) takes ~3.5 minute.

Comment: thank you , I will try using ssd I have 5m rows

Comment: Don't blink; it might already be finished.